# Return the last non-blank value in a row, but only if it matches the column header

Tags: excel

Thank you for kindly  answering my question "Return the last non-blank value in a row, but only if it matches the column header."

The formula you gave me was:

=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/((D2:H2<>"")*(D$1:H$1="D")),D2:H2),"")

I tried it, but now nothing returns to my End Date column.

Do I need to tell Excel which row the "D" appears (ie., over the last non-blank cell that I want to return)?  The "D" headers appear in the row above my data range (ie., row 1).

With Grateful Thanks

~ Jay

Comment: You say "but only if 'it matches the column header." What is "it"? As you saying "if the last non-blank value in a row is equal to the row letter, return it"? And otherwise return what? Zero? Blank? Where did your formula come from? "formula you gave me"...??? Or do you want to return the value in the column that has the header `D`, if that is the last non-blank column?...

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,1/((D2:H2<>"")*(D$1:H$1="D")),D2:H2),"")

                ^ 
                | 
                | changed the 2 to a 1
```

The expression `1/((D2:H2<>"")*(D$1:H$1))` can only ever be `1` (if both conditions are true) or `#DIV0` (when both are false) - so searching for the value `2` in this expression will never work.

Comment: Dear Floris,  I tried this just now and it doesn't work, either.  May I attach or send you a simple test copy Excel sheet of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Again, my headers in row 1 are: Start /End/Hrs/D/L/D/L/D/L

Comment: The formula I need would go in the next row below "End"

Comment: Dear Floris,  I copied all this on to a clean Excel sheet and it works!  So it must be some simple formatting conundrum in my current sheet.  Now that I know I have it, I can find it.

Comment: With Grateful Thanks for your time~!

Comment: PS.  interestingly enough, it only works with the original formula you sent me  =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/((D2:H2<>"")*(D$1:H$1="D")),D2:H2),"")

Comment: Not the current one =IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,1/((D2:H2<>"")*(D$1:H$1="D")),D2:H2),"")

Comment: I got my original formula online.  But as I said, the =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/((D2:H2<>"")*(D$1:H$1="D")),D2:H2),"") works like a dream now that I've inserted it into a fresh sheet.  Go figure.

Comment: Well I am completely puzzled but glad you sorted it out.

Comment: I think I found what the issue was:  Here's the formula in my spreadsheet as it works now:  =IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/((K6:DA6<>"")*(K$5:DA$5="D")),K6:DA6),"").   You'll notice that the range inside the second pair of parenthesis refers to row 5, while the first and last pair of parenthesis refer to row 6.  That was the trick.  Row 5 contains the headers where "D" and "L" are located.  Row 6 is where my data entries and return cells are.  It's a beautiful, this thing we've created.  I'm beholden to you.

Comment: Forgive my delay in answering your previous question: The "it" I was referring to was the value (ie., "Return the last non-blank value in a row, but only if it [the value to be returned] matches the column header [above it]." The value I wanted returned were dates in the alternate columns of the row (the other columns were lengths, in decimals.)  At any rate, it all works beautifully.  Thanks to your help, I was able to solve a problem that I've been banging my head against for 5 days. What a relief!

Comment: I don't feel I was much help but I am glad you solved your problem.